# open link from ms word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

we have a tools developed by rails 3.1.8, which export products information to ms word, then product owner could click link in word to edit the product details in our application if some update from product lines.

**here is the problem: when we hit the link in word, it will go to the homepage not the edit page.**

so we use devise to perform authentication, in routes:

```
devise_for :users do
  get "login" => "devise/sessions#new"
  get "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
```

develop logging:

```
Started GET "/products/24/edit" for 10.237.133.26 at 2012-12-17 15:24:49 +0800
  Processing by ProductsController#edit as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"24"}
Completed   in 4ms

Session: {"as:products"=>{:list=>{}}, "input_device_type"=>"MOUSE", "hover_supported"=>true, "user_return_to"=>"/products/24/edit", "flash"=>#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00000006c80540 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={:alert=>"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}, @now=nil>, "_csrf_token"=>"xvfpiA69SZas+iHoCy5NQRMOifXtomG3RoLaYvPQsSw="}


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.237.133.26 at 2012-12-17 15:24:49 +0800
 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/activescaffold (3.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (50.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (3.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 91ms (Views: 62.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.237.133.26 at 2012-12-17 15:24:50 +0800
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 15 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http:// localhost:30033/
Completed 302 Found in 33ms

Session: {"input_device_type"=>"MOUSE", "hover_supported"=>true, "_csrf_token"=>"Pa8zGbsbms4EwRUO4G7MyJFv7ztKe33WICeY7qpYgeQ=", "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [15], nil], "flash"=>#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00000006fec508 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={:alert=>"You are already signed in."}, @now=nil>}


Started GET "/" for 10.237.133.26 at 2012-12-17 15:24:51 +0800
  Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 15 LIMIT 1
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (3.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 14.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

Does anybody has better solutions?

Comment: I try this proposal, it seems not work: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office have its own mechanism to identify the link(i.e Protocol Discovery).

This needs to be handled differently in rails. MS office make request using OPTIONS http method and followed till first 200 response then opens the same url(redirected url in your case) in browser window.

Here, Devise keeps track of requested_url inside session but browser initiate new session with login url so devise can not redirect back it to link click inside the ms doc.

Here is a good solution of handling the case
http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/2318-dealing-with-microsoft-office-protocol-discovery-in-rails

Comment: Sorry for lat response, I performed the testing and handled some urgent issues. I print the request and the found out the section of request_method, it show us 'GET', not options. @request_method="GET", @filtered_parameters={"action"=>"edit", "controller"=>"products", "id"=>"3861"}, @method="GET", @fullpath="/products/3861/edit">